# Finding the longest "number sequence" in a string using only a single regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, strategy-pattern

I want to find a single regex which matches the longest numerical string in a URL.
I.e for the URL: `http://stackoverflow.com/1234/questions/123456789/ask`, I would like it to return : `123456789`

I thought I could use : `([\d]+)`

However this returns the first match from the left, not the longest. 
Any ideas :) ?

---

This regex will be used as an input to a strategy pattern, which extracts certain characteristics from urls:

```
 public static String parse(String url, String RegEx) {

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher m = pattern.matcher(url);
  if (m.find()) {
    return m.group(1);
  }

return null;
```

}

So it would be much tidier if I could use a single regex. :( –

Comment: This is simply not possible without modifications / better specifications in a single regex. You'll need some programming logic additionally. Period.

Comment: Get all matches based on `\b\d+\b` and iterate the matches to find the longest length

Comment: Additionally, no brackets are needed in this case, you can very well write `\d+` without any parentheses at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex. Just iterate the characters:

```
String longest = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < str.length()) {
  while (i < str.length() && !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
    ++i;
  }
  int start = i;
  while (i < str.length() && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
    ++i;
  }
  if (i - start > longest.length()) {
    longest = str.substring(start, i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andy already gave a non-regex answer, which is probably faster, but if you want to use regex, you must, as @Jan points out, add logic, e.g.:

```
public String findLongestNumber(String input) {
    String longestMatch = "";
    int maxLength = 0;
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([\\d]+)").matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        String currentMatch = m.group();
        int currentLength = currentMatch.length();
        if (currentLength > maxLength) {
            maxLength = currentLength;
            longestMatch = currentMatch;
        }

    }

    return longestMatch;
}
```

t

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with pure Regex, however I would do it this way (using Stream Max and Regex) :

```
    String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/1234/questions/123456789/ask";
    Pattern biggest = Pattern.compile("/(\\d+)/");
    Matcher m = biggest.matcher(url);
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    while(m.find()){
        matches.add(m.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println(matches.parallelStream().max((String a, String b) -> Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length())).get());
```

Will print : 123456789